# Trying to find all tasks that belong to a project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking to find a way to pull all tasks that belong to a project where the project has a specific team attribute.

1. Project `has_many` tasks
2. Tasks `has_one` project

My project has a table column called `team`. 
I'm looking for a way to call the tasks in my project controller to show on my project index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your models relationships should be like below:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end
```

Task model:

```
 class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

## projects controller

```
def index
  @projects = Project.where(column_name: 'some_value')
end
```

In project views

```
 <% @projects.includes(:tasks).each do |project|%>
    <% project.tasks.each do |task| %>
       <%= task.team %>
    <% end %>

   ... and attributes so on
 <% end %>
```

Comment: This won't work because `.where` returns a collection. You probably want to use `find_by`

Comment: I'd like to show all tasks for many projects. Is there a way to do this with the where clause? To be more specific, I'm trying to display all tasks for any project that has a specific team name. That means I'll most likely get many projects each with many tasks.

Comment: here you will get the list of projects and then you can iteration each project and get the tasks of each projects, please check updated answer.

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for but it's too detailed for the end-user. I'm looking to have a grand total displayed instead of each individual project/task

Comment: so do you want only count of tasks to which each project belongs ?

Comment: if so then you can get this by
 <% @projects.includes(:tasks).each do |project|%>

        <%= project.tasks.count %>

<% end %>

Comment: Essentially, I'll be using this first graph on Chartkick (http://chartkick.com/) to display the total number of completed tasks for all projects that belong to a specific team. How would I iterate over all of the projects and get 1 grand total and group_by_day?

Answer (score 1):

```
# projects controller

def index
  @tasks = Project.find_by(team: 'some_team').tasks
end
```

Assuming you have a column in your `projects` table called `team`, this should work. Now, in your `index` view, you can access each tasks using the `@tasks` variable.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Can you tell me how I might be able to show the totals for the team tasks? Each task has a processMetric and outcomeMetric that I'm trying total by day.